# What's the procedure to associate a new remote with a 2006 Cobalt?

Tags: chevrolet, keyless-entry, cobalt, delta

How do I associate a new keyless entry remote on a 2006 Chevrolet Cobalt?  I've got the original chipped keys.

Comment: I believe that it requires a scan tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it requires a scan tool.  [This link](http://www.automotivehelper.com/topic601996.htm) is for a 2005 Cobalt, but it should be the same as a 2006.  Also, according to [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_5505869_program-gm-keyless-remotes.html):

> Some vehicles, such as the Chevrolet Cobalt, Pontiac G6 and Chevrolet Malibu, do not have programmable remote systems.